# apache flink: how to interpret DataStream.print output?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am a newbie in Flink, trying to understand how it is to be used most effectively.

I am trying with Window APIs, reading from a CSV file. The rows read are transformed into a case class, thus

```
case class IncomingDataUnit (
sensorUUID: String, radiationLevel: Int,photoSensor: Float,
humidity: Float,timeStamp: Long, ambientTemperature: Float)
  extends Serializable {

}
```

and, this is how I read the rows:

```
env.readTextFile(inputPath).map(datum => {
      val fields = datum.split(",")
      IncomingDataUnit(
        fields(0),              // sensorUUID
        fields(1).toInt,        // radiationLevel
        fields(2).toFloat,      // photoSensor
        fields(3).toFloat,      // humidity
        fields(4).toLong,       // timeStamp
        fields(5).toFloat       // ambientTemperature
      )
    })
```

Later, using a simple window, I am trying to print the maximum *ambient temperature* , thus:

```
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime)

val readings =
      readIncomingReadings(env,"./sampleIOTTiny.csv")
      .map(e => (e.sensorUUID,e.ambientTemperature))
      .timeWindowAll(Time.of(5,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
      .trigger(CountTrigger.of(5))
      .evictor(CountEvictor.of(4))
      .max(1)

readings.print
```

Output contains these (from a bunch of DEBUG log statements):

```
1> (probe-987f2cb6,29.43)
1> (probe-987f2cb6,29.43)
3> (probe-dccefede,30.02)
3> (probe-42a9ddca,22.07)
2> (probe-df2d4cad,22.87)
2> (probe-20c609fb,27.62)
4> (probe-dccefede,30.02)
```

What I am trying to understand is that how does one interpret this? What do **repeated 1>s** represent?

What is also baffling me is that *probe-987f2cb6* doesn't correspond to *ambient temperature* 29.43 in my data set. It corresponds to a different value (14.72 to be exact).

Just for reference, here is the dataset:

```
probe-f076c2b0,201,842.53,75.5372,1448028160,29.37
probe-dccefede,199,749.25,78.6057,1448028160,27.46
probe-f29f9662,199,821.81,81.7831,1448028160,22.35
probe-5dac1d9f,195,870.71,83.1028,1448028160,15.98
probe-6c75cfbe,198,830.06,82.5607,1448028160,30.02
probe-4d78b545,204,778.42,78.412,1448028160,25.92
probe-400c5cdf,204,711.65,73.585,1448028160,22.18
probe-df2d4cad,199,820.8,72.936,1448028161,16.18
probe-f4ef109e,199,785.68,77.5647,1448028161,16.36
probe-3fac3350,200,720.12,78.2073,1448028161,19.19
probe-42a9ddca,193,819.12,74.3712,1448028161,22.07
probe-252a5bbd,197,710.32,80.6072,1448028161,14.64
probe-987f2cb6,200,750.4,76.0533,1448028161,14.72
probe-24444323,197,816.06,84.0816,1448028161,4.405
probe-6dd6fdc4,201,717.64,78.4031,1448028161,29.43
probe-20c609fb,204,804.37,84.5243,1448028161,22.87
probe-c027fdc9,195,858.61,81.7682,1448028161,24.47
probe-2c6cd3de,198,826.96,85.26,1448028162,18.99
probe-960906ca,197,797.63,77.4359,1448028162,27.62
```

There's probably a lot that I am missing. Please prod me.

Forgot to mention: I am using **Flink 0.10.0.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ">X" represent the task ID of the parallel task that does print the result tuple. I am just wondering why the output shows values 1 to 4 -- as you are using a **non-parallel** window (the data stream is not partitioned via `.keyBy()`) and I would expect the print to be chained and non-parallel either. But maybe it is not and 4 parallel print tasks are running.

About your result: if the window fires, the max over field 1 is computed over all tuples and the **head** tuple's value of the window is used for field 0. If you want to return the complete tuple that contains the max value, you can use `maxBy()` instead of `max()`.

Comment: @matthias-j-sax: now that you mention, I gather some courage to state that this was my question too - why 4 different tasks when I have not asked for any parallelism specifically. As for _maxBy_ instead of _max_, I will try that. But I am wondering if it is semantically correct to combine maxed field '1' with head-reacord-field '0'. How is such an interpretation useful?

Comment: Flink always uses a default parallelism according to your hardware (I guess you have a 4-core machine). Nevertheless, the non-parallel window will be executed in a single thread -- but this does not apply to your other operators. You can of course set the default parallelism explicitly to one via `StreamExecutionEnvironment.setParallelism(int)` (or individually for each operator: `operator.setParallelism(int)`).
`max`  is useful on key-streams to output the aggregate together with the key-attribute which is the same for all tuples in the window.

Comment: We are mixing two things in this question: interpretation of the output which has been answered and window semantics. Regarding the window semantics: You are using processing time, and a time window of 5 msec with count trigger and count evictor. By specifying the count trigger, you override the time trigger, i.e., the window is NOT triggered after 5 msec. Instead it is triggered after 5 elements arrived. The evictor is called BEFORE the window function is applied and removes the first four elements from the windows. Hence, max() is only applied on the last received element.

Comment: @FabianHueske: thanks for the explanations. It is clearer to me now. When I accept the answer, I guess it will be credited to Matthias, but both of you have taken time to explain. Many thanks.

Comment: On a different note, I have mailed to user-group too, inquiring about this particular window semantics. I mention it just so that my question doesn't seem repetitive there.

Comment: I suggest we discuss the issue on the mailing list and you post an update here after we figured it out. It might require some more back and forth ;-)

Comment: I have to correct my previous comment. A CountEvictor(4) will not remove 4 elements, but only KEEP 4 elements. So given a CountTrigger(5), the first element in the window is removed before the window function (max) is applied.